# How to remove lingering print job in C# word app

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word

I've created a c# program that prints a Word doc using MergeFields and a template.

When I run the program a 2nd/3rd time. The program prints out the 1st iteration of the program every time.

Any ideas?

There doesn't appear to be a print job left over the iteration.

Script being used is below

```
Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wordDocument = new Word.Document();

try
{
    Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;

    foreach (Word.Field myMergeField in wordDocument.Fields)
    {
        Word.Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
        String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;
        if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
        {
            Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
            Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
            String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);
            fieldName = fieldName.Trim();



            #region Merge fields

            // Principal Contractor

            if (fieldName == "strJobName")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                if (summary.GetName() == String.Empty || summary.GetName() == null)
                {
                    selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    selection.TypeText(summary.GetName());
                }
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }


    object copies = "1";
    object pages = "";
    object range = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;
    object items = Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent;
    object pageType = Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages;
    object oTrue = true;
    object oFalse = false;

    wordDocument.PrintOut(ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref range, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref oFalse, ref oTrue,
        Type.Missing, ref oFalse, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    // Clean up!
    if (wordDocument != null) wordDocument.Close();
    wordApplication.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

Comment: little confused by 1st iteration and 2nd/3rd iterations - what exactly is changing between them? - the most obvious portion would be that once you replace all the fields with text - there wont be anything to change unless you've reopened the document template which doesnt seem covered here - as your wordDocument is "new" there would be nothing in it.

Comment: Hello BugFinder. I run the program and it works as expected first time round. The only thing that actually changes between that and the next time I run the program is the values contained within the mergefileds.

Comment: Ok so how does the template for the fields end up in the new doc?

Comment: @BugFinder Hey, I think I'm narrowing it down slowly. I don't think it's actually a print issue any more! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466531/c-sharp-overwriting-word-template-merge-fields